# Attempting to construct a milage calculator

Tags: c++

I am attempting to construct a mileage calculator. The design is like this,

If a person drives 100 miles or less then the amount they shall be paid 25 cent per mile.

If a person drives in excess of 100 miles, they shall be paid the initial 25 cents for their first 100 miles in addition to 15 cents for every mile over 100 mile...

So an example would be

10 miles would earn the person a dollar, while 250 miles would earn (25 for the first 100 + 22.50 for the second 150) to a grand total of 47.50..

When I hit start without debugging, the program goes to the black screen to put values in. But then I receive an error message.. I am trying to figure out what it means.

I am using microsoft visual studio 2008. C++ coding.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int varOne ;

    cout << "Enter your favorite number" << endl;
    cin << varOne << endl;

    if(varOne <= 100)
        cout << (1/4)*(varOne)<<  endl;

    if (varOne>= 100)
        cout << (.15 * (varOne-100)) + (.25 * 100) <, endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Debug Error!

Program ... isual Studio

2008\Projects\practice\Debug\rorioodweorrfhur.exe
Module: ... isual studio
2008\Projects\practice\Debug\rorioodweorfhur.exe
File:

Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'var1' is being used without being initialized.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

Comment: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html for information about **how to post a question about code that doesn't work**.

Comment: Is that the **real code** that you're running?  I'm not sure how you got that to compile.

Comment: Yes that is the real code I am running.. What makes you say that?

Comment: Its coding errors, I've shown your errors and their corrections as an answer, check it out

Comment: ***Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'var1' is being used without being initialized.*** This is hard to help when the code does not match the error. There is no var1 in the code you posted. Also this is not a compiler error. Although you should have had a warning about this.

Comment: Voting to close as comments here and below strongly reflect that the code posted here is **not** the code being run.

Comment: Your Google drive pictures links were broken, so I removed those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some simple errors I noticed in your code

```
 cin << varOne << endl;
```

It should be

```
 cin >> varOne ;
```

Next error

```
cout << (.15 * (varOne-100)) + (.25 * 100) <, endl;
```

This should be

```
cout << (.15 * (varOne-100)) + (.25 * 100) << endl;
```

Here are some logical errors.

In your If statements, you are checking >= and <= , Check for equality only once. Change

```
if(varOne <= 100)
```

to

```
if(varOne < 100)
```

Also change

```
cout<< (1/4)*(varOne) << endl;
```

to

```
cout<< (varOne)/4 << endl;
```

This is because 1/4 will give 0

Comment: Dang! I did not even see those! Thank you, but the error message I receive at the end persists!

Comment: Show that error message, your code compiled without any errors on my compiler ( although its gcc compiler ).

Comment: I cant see a var1 in your program

Comment: I don't know what the problem is now as your code ran on my compiler without any errors. Maybe its got something to do with your Visual C++ compiler

Comment: You must not be running the code that you have posted. Maybe its still an old version and the current version did not compile. Look carefully at any compiler errors.

Comment: I've noticed an error on my part, if you simply copied the correction I gave you onto your code, it might cause error because I wrote varone instead of varOne

Comment: You should Probably copy your entire code after corrections, close your program , open it again, paste your code and try running again ( maybe it will work, who knows!!! won't hurt to try ).

Comment: If still not getting it done, then ask this as a separate question with the error as your tittle and with a visual c++ tag.